# Bibliography entries with pubstate and no date, in authortitle style

Tags: biblatex

I'd like to refer to an article which has apparently been accepted for publication by a journal but yet to be published (other than unofficially on the arXiv).
To do so, I'm using the `pubstate` field.
Unfortunately, there's no official date scheduled for publication.
This means my bibliography entries end up with a pair of brackets surrounding an empty string.
(Note that I'm using `authortitle` style.)

In this situation, is it possible to have biblatex say print "(forthcoming)" in place of a missing date?

## Attempted solution

I tried to solve this problem as follows.
Here's a MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{example1,
    title = "My first article",
    author = "A. N. Author",
    journal = "Journal of Stuff",
    pubstate = "inpreparation",
}

@article{example2,
    title = "My second article",
    crossref = "example1",
    pubstate = "submitted",
}

@article{example3,
    title = "My third article",
    crossref = "example1",
    pubstate = "forthcoming"
}

@article{example4,
    title = "My fourth article",
    crossref = "example1",
    pubstate = "inpress"
}

@article{example5,
    title = "My fifth article",
    crossref = "example1",
    pubstate = "prepublished"
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authortitle,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Here's my long-winded citation: \cites{example1}{example2}{example3}{example4}{example5}.
Here's one from the \texttt{biblatex} example: \cite{springer}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: First attempt: pubstate, journal, no date]

I did some searching and came across an [answer of Andrew Swann](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154367/82389).
Unfortunately I'm trying to use this with the `authortitle` style rather than `authordate`.
After some more searching and reading the biblatex manual, I attempted to use the pubstate as a `fake date' if no date was provided.
I added the following to the preamble.

```
\renewbibmacro*{date}{%
    \ifboolexpr{ test {\iffieldundef{date}} and not test {\iffieldundef{pubstate}} }%
    {\printfield{pubstate}}%
    {\printfield{date}}%
}

\renewbibmacro*{addendum+pubstate}{%
    \printfield{addendum}%
}
```

The result was mixed.

[image: Second attempt: vanishing dates in Springer]

This makes the undated references behave as I had intended.
Unfortunately I managed to wipe out the date for the Springer reference.
Is there a better (correct?) way to deal with this using biblatex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `biblatex` `date` is only a 'virtual' field, within `biblatex` you can only access its parts `year`, `month`, `day`, .... Of course in the `.bib` file `date` is very much real.

If you want to check if there is no date, check for `year` (this is what Andrew does in [his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154367/35864), but he has to check for a special `year` field)

```
\renewbibmacro*{date}{%
  \ifboolexpr{ test {\iffieldundef{year}} and not test {\iffieldundef{pubstate}} }%
    {\printfield{pubstate}}%
    {\printdate}}

\renewbibmacro*{addendum+pubstate}{%
  \printfield{addendum}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iffieldundef{year}
    {}
    {\printfield{pubstate}}}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect. So is `date` mainly meant for entering dates in one field in the `.bbl` file, rather than spread out across three fields?

Comment: @DavidRobertson Exactly, `date` is the correct field to input the data in the `.bib`, but for internal reasons it is easier to handle the split-up parts of the `date` in `biblatex` macros.