# How to omit year from biblatex bibliography

Tags: biblatex, biber

I am using a bib file that looks something like this (saved as ref.bib):

```
@article{key1, 
    author = {Joe Smith},
    journal={A journal}, 
    title = {An article}, 
    year = {2017}}

@article{key2, 
    author = {Joe Smith}, 
    title = {A second article}, 
    journal = {},
    year = {2017}, 
    pubstate={Draft}}
```

With a latex file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ref.bib}

\begin{document}
\section{ONE}
\begin{refsection}
  \nocite{key1}
  \printbibliography{}
\end{refsection}

\section{TWO}
\begin{refsection}
  \nocite{key2}
  \printbibliography{}
\end{refsection}
\end{document}
```

But I would like to omit the year from the second bibliography since it is an unpublished draft. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Use `@unpublished`, then year can be omitted.

Comment: `key2` is definitely not an `@article` if it has no `journal` and has not yet been published. There is `@unpublished`, but also `@online` if you got the work from a pre-print server.

Comment: Is this for a CV/list of your publications?

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. Using @unpublished and omitting the year still puts in `(n.d.)`, which I don't want. @moewe - yes, it is for a CV

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `@unpublished` and the `pubstate` field. With

```
\DeclareLabeldate{%
  \field{date}
  \field{year}
  \field{eventdate}
  \field{origdate}
  \field{urldate}
  \field{pubstate}
  \literal{nodate}
}
```

you get to see the `pubstate` in the brackets after the author name in the bibliography. To avoid printing the `pubstate` twice in that case we redefine `addendum+pubstate`.

This is similar to Andrew's answer in [Biblatex: How to get “Author (forthcoming)” when pubstate=forthcoming is set, instead of “Author (n.d.)”?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154363/35864), but ultimately a bit simpler.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\DeclareLabeldate{%
  \field{date}
  \field{year}
  \field{eventdate}
  \field{origdate}
  \field{urldate}
  \field{pubstate}
  \literal{nodate}
}

\renewbibmacro*{addendum+pubstate}{%
  \printfield{addendum}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iffieldequalstr{labeldatesource}{pubstate}
    {}
    {\printfield{pubstate}}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{key1, 
  author  = {Joe Smith},
  journal = {A journal}, 
  title   = {An article}, 
  year    = {2017},
}

@unpublished{key2, 
  author   = {Joe Smith}, 
  title    = {A second article}, 
  pubstate = {draft},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{key1} and \cite{key2}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: example]