# showing year and pubstate together in bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

## Overview

Using `biblatex`, I'd like to display the `year` and `pubstate` fields together in a bibliography.

I've suppressed the pubstate field from the end of the bibliography entry by renewing the `addendum+pubstate` macro as discussed in [these](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154367/90570) [two](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/367423/90570) answers.

## Current MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{public2018,
  author = {Sam Public},
  year = {2018},
  pubstate = {in preparation},
  journal = {Amazing Ideas},
  title = {Some Hargle Bargle},
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\renewbibmacro*{addendum+pubstate}{%
  \printfield{addendum}}

\begin{document}
\cite{public2018}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

## Output

The current output is like this:

[image]

## What I'd like to see

I'd like to see something more like this:

[image]

I obtain the above by offloading the pubstate into the `year` field, which is terrible in many ways, least of which is that it requires hacks to sort correctly.

So I imagine I need to renew a macro (or make a new macro?) of some sort, but I don't know which one or quite how it needs to be done.  Any guidance anyone could offer would be most welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It needs a bit of fiddling with the macros to get this right for `authoryear-comp`, but you should be good with the following code. Note that it is specifically designed to work with the standard `mergedate` settings; if you use other settings, you may need to tweak the `date+extradate` macro.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{public2018,
  author   = {Sam Public},
  year     = {2018},
  pubstate = {inpreparation},
  journal  = {Amazing Ideas},
  title    = {Some Hargle Bargle},
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:labeldate+extradate}{%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[bibhyperref]{%
       \printlabeldateextra
       \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
       \printfield{pubstate}}}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:extradate}{%
  \iffieldundef{extradate}
    {}
    {\printtext[bibhyperref]{%
       \printfield{extradate}%
       \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
       \printfield{pubstate}}}}

\renewbibmacro*{date+extradate}{%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
       \iflabeldateisdate
         {\printdateextra}
         {\printlabeldateextra}%
       \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
       \printfield{pubstate}}}}

\renewbibmacro*{addendum+pubstate}{%
  \printfield{addendum}}

\begin{document}
\cite{public2018}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note how I wrote `pubstate = {inpreparation},` to make use of the predefined localisation string `inpreparation`.