# Unwanted parentheses at the end of reference in bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I'm writing an article at Overleaf and originally had the problem that publications that I wanted to list as "forthcoming" or "to appear" would appear as (n.d.) instead. I managed to solve that problem by reading this thread : [Biblatex: How to get "Author (forthcoming)" when pubstate=forthcoming is set, instead of "Author (n.d.)"?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154363/biblatex-how-to-get-author-forthcoming-when-pubstate-forthcoming-is-set-in)

I now use the same renew-macro-command which is recommended in that thread (see MWE below). However, for the relevant entry, there is now an extra parentheses at the end of the entry in the bibliography.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,  style=authoryear-comp, sortcites=false, maxcitenames=2, mincitenames=1, maxbibnames=4, uniquelist=false, uniquename=false, useprefix=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ref.bib}

\DeclareLabeldate{%
  \field{year}
  \field{eventdate}
  \field{origdate}
  \field{urldate}
  \field{pubstate}
  \literal{nodate}
  }
  
  \renewbibmacro*{addendum+pubstate}{%
  \printfield{addendum}%
  \iffieldequalstr{labeldatesource}{pubstate}{}
  {\newunit\newblock\printfield{pubstate}}}

\begin{document}

Bla bla \cite{PetrovaXXX}

\end{document}
```

where the `ref.bib` looks like this:

```
@Article{PetrovaXXX,
author = {Petrova, Svetlana},
pubstate = {to appear},
title = {Hauptsätze mit Verbspäterstellung im Althochdeutschen: Bestand, Distribution, Interpretation},
journaltitle = {Beträge zur Geschichte der deutschen Sprache und Litteratur},

}
```

And where the bibliography ends up looking like this, note the extra parentheses at the end:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to tex,sx,  You can format your code block by highlighting it with your mouse, then clicking on the `{}` icon above the question box.